# How to find the Length of the text file in windows forms vc++?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

Hi Can you please let me know how to find the file size, below is the code I am using to create the file & to write the data to the file.

```
   String^ path = "C:\\Users\\Mani\\Desktop\\"+textBox2->Text+".txt";
   StreamWriter^ sw ; 
   if ( !File::Exists( path ) )
   {
      File_flag = 1;
      // Create the file.   
      sw = File::CreateText( path );
      sw->WriteLine("***Log File***");
      sw->WriteLine(DateTime::Now);
      sw->WriteLine("**************");       
   }
```

Comment: The code snippet makes little sense, you can't find the size of a file that doesn't exist.  Post relevant code and explain why this is necessary.

Comment: yes, with that code I am creating a file & writing data to it. 

My problem is: In parallel I need to trace the file size while writing the data.?